# Website image spacing correctly

Tags: html, css, margin, spacing

I want my images next to each other with a little margin in between. But when I do `margin-right: 10px; on each div the last image wont align with my title bar.

[image]

How can I give the divs a space in between without having a space on the right of the last div?

Note: The content is dynamic, so I cant make a div to hold the 4 divs.

Comment: combination of float, margin and width?

Comment: Are there only going to be 4 divs, or are they rows of 4 of unknown length?

Comment: The big question is: is it always 4? If you want three divs to stretch the whole width and then four then you can't do that dynamically (because CSS has no idea _how many elements_ there are)

Comment: I wont always be 4 (as I said in the description). The divs all have the same width. When there are only 3 (for example) they dont need to stretch.

Comment: Please post your code showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can do, I'll just show one of them.

**EDIT 1:** solution for multiple rows by using `nth-child`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/s0xLfcrx/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="box">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>f</div>
    <div>g</div>
    <div>h</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar, .box {
    width: 460px;
}

.bar {
    background: lime;
    height: 20px;
}

.box {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}

.box > div {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: gold;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.box > div:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.box > div:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

**ORIGINAL DEMO (for only 1 row):**

http://jsfiddle.net/s0xLfcrx/

Comment: first-child and last-child wont work. the content is dynamic. There are more divs loaded in there every day.

Comment: @WardP He could replace it with `.box > div:nth-child(5n), .box:first-child {}` (for the first and every fifth) and `.box > div:nth-child(5n-1)` (every fourth child)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `justify-content: space-between`. This creates even spacing inbetween each of the image containers and pushes the first and last element to the edges of the parent div.

Your html:

```css
.container {
      width: 346px;
    }
    .title-bar {
      background-color: #ccc;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .flex-container {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      
      -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -moz-flex;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .space-between { 
      -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
      justify-content: space-between; 
    }
    .image-container {
      background: #ccc;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 60px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 50px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 2em;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="title-bar">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-container space-between">
        <div class="image-container">1</div>
        <div class="image-container">2</div>
        <div class="image-container">3</div>
        <div class="image-container">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The styling for the image-containers in the code above is just an example - if you have an unknown number of divs loading you either fix the width, or make them fluid and the container width will need to be fluid (unless you want it fixed of course).

Comment: Throw it in a SO snippet so I can see it working and I'll +1 it!

Comment: ok great - i haven't used that feature yet so a good chance to try it :)

Comment: Oke this might be a stupid question. But why do you use two different classes for flex-container space-between ? Instead of putting the css code  in the same class.

Comment: you don't have to, it's just for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple CSS

```
.div { width: 25%; text-align: center; padding: 5px; box-sizing: border-box; }
.div img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `width: 25%` mean theres no margin to space out?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean.. will amend

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this with variable widths:

```css
.titlebar {
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
}

.item25 {
    width: calc(25% - 11px);
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.no-margin {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="titlebar"></div>
<div class="item25"></div>
<div class="item25"></div>
<div class="item25"></div>
<div class="item25 no-margin"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do but if you need **RESPONSIVE** for this then use this solution:

```css
body{font-family:arial;}
h1{
  display:block;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  background:#0af;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}
.layer{
  display:block;
  overflow:auto;
}
.layer > div{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:10px 10px 10px 0px;
  width:    -moz-calc(25% - 7.5px);
  width: -webkit-calc(25% - 7.5px);
  width:         calc(25% - 7.5px);
  background-color:#000;
  height:30px;
  
}
.layer > div:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title bar</h1>
<div class="layer">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div>
</div>
```